# Connecting to Guest Machine apache from another computer

Tags: apache, centos, virtualbox

I can ping my guest machine from host and connect to apache from my host, but others can't connect to my apache server. Any ideas? Running CentOS on virtualbox

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many people here willing to help, but please make sure you've showed what you've tried, what didn't work, and the context of your question. Please make sure you've read [**how-to-ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to better attract people's expenditure of time and effort. Moreover, since this isn't a programming related question, you'd be better to post it over at SuperUser once you're familiar with how to properly ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem a year ago , but you just have to do is to configure the NAT ports on virualbox

Comment: Which ports to configure??